# Mathematical notation/representation of a sum-product expression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation, products

I can write a general term, say $m$th term $T_m$, as a sum of $2^{m-1}$ terms in which each term contains two type of variables, i.e., $a_{i,j}$ and $b_i$ where $i,j\in 0,\cdots,m$. However, I do not see any pattern to write it in compact form with sum and product notations. But I know that each term at least has one $a_{i,j}$ and $b_i$ product at most has product with  $m$ number of $a_{i,j}$ and $m$ number of $b_i$.

E.g., the 4th term, i.e., $m=4$ so I have $2^3=8$ terms where $T_4$ is:
$$T_4=a_{0,4}b_0 +a_{0,3}a_{3,4}b_0b_4+a_{0,1}a_{1,4}b_0b_1 +a_{0,2}a_{2,4}b_0b_0 +a_{0,1}a_{1,2}a_{2,4}b_0b_1b_2 +a_{0,1}a_{1,3}a_{3,4}b_0b_1b_4 +a_{0,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,4}b_0b_3b_4 +a_{0,1}a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,4}b_0b_1b_3b_4$$

I can notice that number of $a_{i,j}$s and $b_i$s are equal for a given term.

Can someone help me to write $T_m$ expression in general way, $\sum_{i,j}^{}\prod_{i,j}^{}a_{i,j}b_i$, which may not give the exact expression but to represent the rough pattern?

By including the fact that each term at least has one $a_{i,j}$ and $b_i$ product (e.g., $a_{0,4}b_0$), and  at most has product with  $m$ number of $a_{i,j}$ and $m$ number of $b_i$ (e.g., $a_{0,1}a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,4}b_0b_1b_3b_4$).

Comment: It seems that you have a term involving $b_0b_0$ (repetition of same symbol). Is this with intention?
 Without this you could have written it like $T_n=\sum_p (\prod_{(i,j)\in I_{n,p}} a_{i,j}) (\prod_{k\in J_{n,p}} b_k)$ where $I_{n,p}$ and $J_{n,p}$ are certain subsets of ${\mathbb N}^2$ and ${\mathbb N}$, respectively. Here, ${\mathbb N}$ contains $0$.

Comment: Actually $b_0=1$. I included it because otherwise I get some terms only with $a_{i,j}$s, and sometimes number of $a_{i,j}$s and $b_i$s in a given term is different. I think that it is not an issue with your notation. is that right?

Comment: Ok, not an issue then, and my suggestion should work. The point is to get hold of the subsets $I_{n,p}$ and $J_{n,p}$, which may, or may not, be  so easy. Given those it should be easy to program it on a computer.

Comment: Yes, helpful suggestions.